# PHPExcel check the file is saved

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). I am trying to save the file a directory ( The file is saved ). Can I confirm the file is saved.? We use `$writer->save($filename);` to save the file.
I tried like

```
if( $writer->save($filename) ){
    echo "File successfully saved";
}
```

Also like

```
 if( $writer->save($filename) === true){
    echo "File successfully saved";
 }
```

Can anyone help.?
Thanks in advance.!

Comment: PHPExcel throws Exceptions if it fails; so a try/catch block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHPExcel throws Exceptions if it fails; so a try/catch block

```
try {
    $writer->save($filename);
    echo "File successfully saved";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ', $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. And surprise, the coordinator of PHPExcel answered my question. :)

Comment: Yeah Mark Baker has helped me and many others with his awesome support. Another great answer. I wish stack would allow users to post crypto wallet addresses so we could donate.